# spark on yarn,only one executor on one node works and the allocation is random

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

i run spark-shell with this command：

```
./bin/spark-shell --master yarn --num-executors 16       
--executor-memory 14G --executor-cores 8
```

i have four nodes，every node has 16G memory and 4cores

after i changed num-executors,the spark webUi tell me it worked,
[image]
BUT only one executor on node which named "slave" is running

we could see TRANSFER1 and TRANSFER2 is empty
[image]

how can i solve this, when i submit job the situation has not changed
should i change worker-instances or num-executors and so on

Comment: yes you should set worker-instances in spark-env.sh file.

Comment: sorry，it doesn't work，and i get "SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES was detected (set to '16').
This is deprecated in Spark 1.0+.
 "

Comment: you should try `SPARK_EXECUTOR_INSTANCES`